# Combine Pandas Columns by Corresponding Dictionary Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

I am looking to quickly combine columns that are [genetic complements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qyi6xgOjEk) of each other. I have a large data frame with counts and want to combine columns where the column names are complements. I have a currently have a system that

- Gets the complement of a column name
- Checks the columns names for the compliment
- Adds together the columns if there is a match
- Then deletes the compliment column

However, this is slow (checking every column name) and gives different column names based on the ordering of the columns (i.e. deletes different compliment columns between runs). I was wondering if there was a way to incorporate a dictionary key:value pair to speed the process and keep the output consistent. I have an example dataframe below with the desired result (ATTG|TAAC & CGGG|GCCC are compliments).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ATTG": [3, 6, 0, 1],"CGGG" : [0, 2, 1, 4], 
"TAAC": [0, 1, 0, 1], "GCCC" : [4, 2, 0, 0], "TTTT": [2, 1, 0, 1]}) 

## Current Pseudocode
for item in df.columns():
    if compliment(item) in df.columns():
        df[item] = df[item] + df[compliment(item)]
        del df[compliment(item)]

## Desired Result
df_result = pd.DataFrame({"ATTG": [3, 7, 0, 2],"CGGG" : [4, 4, 1, 4], "TTTT": [2, 1, 0, 1]})
```

Comment: You should probably provide the logic of how you determine the complements but at the very least you can do `df.groupby(complement, axis=1).sum()`. This assumes the `complement` function returns the same value for `item` and its complement (for example it can be a sorting function).

Comment: Hi @ayhan, thank you for the prompt response. Compliment will not return the same value for an item and its compliment. ``` compliment("ATTG") ``` returns "TAAC" and ```compliment("TAAC")``` returns "ATTG". I do think you are on to something with groupby though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate the columns, then assign the columns the translation or original that is sorted first. This allows you to group compliments.

```
import numpy as np

mytrans = str.maketrans('ATCG', 'TAGC')
df.columns = np.sort([df.columns, [x.translate(mytrans) for x in df.columns]], axis=0)[0, :]

df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
#   AAAA  ATTG  CGGG
#0     2     3     4
#1     1     7     4
#2     0     0     1
#3     1     2     4
```

Comment: This works wonderfully! It even works when the order of the columns are changed. Thank you @ALollz